# getValues() return undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy and past some data from one sheet to another sheet. I have the following data structure ->

What I want to copy (sheet1) :

```
dataname  value
data1     value1
data2     value2
data3     value3
data4     value4
```

The final result (sheet2) :

```
day1 value1 value2 value3 value4
day2 value1 value2 value3 value4
day3 value1 value2 value3 value4
```

As you might understand, data on sheet1 are refreshed and copied on daily basis on sheet2.

Here is the script I'm using :

```
function getdata() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet2")
  var data = ss.getRange('B1:B10').getValues()[0][0];
  sheet.appendRow([data[1],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6]]);
}
```

I know it's a very basic question but I still don't understand how `getValues()` really works. With the script above I have the following result :

```
undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined
```

Why is that ? what should I do ?

thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getValues()` returns `Object[][]` which is an array of arrays of values.
When you run `var data = ss.getRange('B1:B10').getValues()[0][0];` you take the top leftmost value and save it in **data**.

I don't know what's in that cell but I assume it's an empty string as you are subsetting it starting at offset 1, which returns undefined rather than throwing an exception.

What you (probably) want to do is something like this :

```
var data = ss.getRange('B1:B10').getValues();
sheet.appendRow([data[1][1],data[2][1],data[3][1],data[4][1],data[5][1],data[6][1]]);
```

Which takes the second column of row 2-7 from `sheet1` and transposes it and appends it to sheet2.

Answer (score 3):

Here, in **data** variable, only first value of range B1:B10 is getting stored. You can see its value by using

```
Logger.log(data);
```

And then go to view-> logs or press ctrl+enter after you have executed the code.

Now, if you want to store sheet values in a 2D array format, you should use this:

```
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();  //Here, ss is what you have declared earlier
```

Now you can check data values using logger.

Alternatively, if you want only B1:B10 values in an array, write like this:

```
var data = ss.getRange("B1:B10").getValues();
```

And now you can use

```
Logger.log(data);
Logger.log(data[3]);
```

And you will get what you wanted.